# Trying to implement if statement using hasClass(), but it's not working

Tags: jquery, css, class

I'm making a memory game. When a card is flipped, the class .flip is added to that card. I'm keeping track of whether the two same cards have been picked by checking to see if the class .flip has been added to both, using the hasClass() method.

However, the jQuery for hasClass() doesn't seem to be working. I'm using a console log to check, but the console isn't printing anything. Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var counter = 0;

        if(counter == 0){
            console.log(counter);
            // set up click/tap panels
            $('.click').toggle(function(){
                counter = 1;
                console.log(counter);
                $(this).addClass('flip');
            },function(){
                /*$(this).removeClass('flip');*/
            });
        }

        if($("#heart-01").hasClass("flip") && $("#heart-02").hasClass("flip")){
            console.log("yo");
        }

    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="heart-01" class="panel click heart">

    <div class="front"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>

</div>

<div id="heart-02" class="panel click heart">

    <div class="front"></div>

    <div class="back"></div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.panel {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 20px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-perspective: 600px;
        -moz-perspective: 600px;
    }

    /* -- Y axis rotation and general style for heart card -- */

    .heart .front {
        float: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 900;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        border: 0;
        background: #333;
        text-align: center;

        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);

        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .heart.flip .front {
        z-index: 900;
        background: #333;

        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);

        -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .heart .back {
        float: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 800;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        border: 0;
        background: url('images/card-01.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
        text-shadow: 1px  1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 

        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

        -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .heart.flip .back {
        z-index: 1000;
        background: url('images/card-01.png') 0 0 no-repeat;

        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);

        box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
.click .front {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
    .click.flip .front {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    .click .back {
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
    .click.flip .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
```

Comment: Note that your use of .toggle() has been [deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: `the jQuery for hasClass() doesn't seem to be working` -- what have you done to verify this?   Do you ever see `counter` in `console.log` with a value > 0?

Comment: @DavidTansey how could he?  This function is only called once, and sets the value to 0 immediately.

Comment: My point exactly -- he should have seen value = 1 if he ever made it to the line of code that does the `addClass()` call...

Comment: @DavidTansey he can make it to the `addClass` call, but the `hasClass` tests aren't inside the event handler, they're called on page load, before the `addClass` calls are ever triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your `if` clause that tests the classes *inside* an event handler.  At the moment it's part of the `document.ready` handler and so the test only ever happens once when the page is first loaded.

Also, the two function version of `.toggle()` has been deprecated.

Try this instead, which appears to have the entire functionality you require:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.click').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('flip');
        if ($('.flip').length === 2) {
            console.log('yo');
        }
    });

});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Xtw58/

Comment: So I need to make an event handler that is called only when the cards are clicked, as opposed to when the page is loaded? Is that what you're doing when you write `$('.click').on('click', function()`?

Comment: Also, I need to make it check to see if both cards have the class "flip." How do I do that using hasClass? I can't just use a counter because the memory game is going to have eight other cards. The counter is there just to establish when the first card has been flipped. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ArielCotton first you have to define what "both cards" means, that is, you have to figure out which cards to test.  The code above only checks that there are two cards with class `flip`, so the next step could be (inside the `if`) to check whether the two `.flip` cards share some other common attribute.